# Can't generate model in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Following the tutorial here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THUG8J3xSYw&list=PLtTtLKRL6UYGxOHToRYnXBynon5plZ7Jd&index=1

trying to generate a model using scaffolding.

I tried this in the terminal

```
mix phx.gen.model Comment comments body:text post_id:references:posts
```

but I get the following in the terminal:

```
** (Mix) The task "phx.gen.model" could not be found. Did you mean "phx.gen.html"?
```

and I tried this in the terminal

```
mix phoenix.gen.model Comment comments body:text post_id:references:posts
```

but I get the following in the terminal:

```
** (Mix) The task "phoenix.gen.model" could not be found
```

Comment: This tutorial is pretty out of date, I recommend using a more recent resource. If you want to know more about why models have been replaced with contexts in 1.3, you can check [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMO28ar0lW8).

Answer (score 7):

in 1.3, model got deprecated. it is now schema

```
mix phx.gen.schema Comment comments body:text post_id:references:posts
```

Comment: In general you should usually take a look at `mix help` in such instances - it will list available tasks. You can also `mix help phx.gen.schema` to get more info on a particular task.